# Buffer is not defined in react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I try to use the react-pdf library to generate pdf.

But when I do this I have an error like this:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
> - install 'assert' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "assert": false } resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\SMAX\OneDrive\Projets
> Autres\exxotax_react\node_modules\browserify-zlib\lib'

Now, after installing some packages the React/Webpack is compiled from npm run start.
But I have the following error:

> Buffer is not defined
> And nothing appear on screen.

How can I fix it?
I tried :

- Install all libraries needed
- Watch on internet some solution

The only solution I saw was something like:

Creating a webpack.config.js and add:

```
resolve: {
extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
fallback: {
    "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
} },
```

But how can I add these lines in the config file? Do I need a new config file/package.json ? If yes how can I do?

Answer (score 2):

To extend create-react-app webpack config, you will need to use craco or rewired instead of react-scripts

Craco: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco

Rewired: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

Answer (score 0):

I finally updated all packages and use a workaorund because of a "conflict" with webpack.

Comment: Which workaround?

Comment: I dont' remember exactly but a package like starlett was bad after updating. I downgrade package like uvicorn etc.